# Android onContextItemSelected() not calls for ListView in ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, listview, menu, android-cursoradapter

I use custom adapter that extends CursorAdapter for my ListView. In the `onCreate()` method I call `registerForContextMenu(lw)`, `onCreateContextMenu()` successfully creates ListView's context menu, but after menu item was clicked `onContextItemSelected()` method is not called.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        linlay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_list);
        lw = new ListView(this);
        lw.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linlay.addView(lw);
        //some operations for init adapter;
        lw.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(lw);
    }
```

Menu creation:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        switch (code) {
        case C.modeFriends:
            menu.add(0, 10, 0, R.string.action_change_birthday);
            menu.add(0, 11, 0, R.string.action_change_template);
            break;
        case C.modeTemplate:
            menu.add(0, 20, 0, R.string.action_edit);
            menu.add(0, 21, 0, R.string.action_delete);
            break;
    }
```

Menu item selection:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId(){
    case 10:

        break;
    case 11:

        break;
    case 20:

        break;
    case 21:

        break;
    }
}
```

In the custom CursorAdapter I overrided newView() and bindView() methods.

P.S. Activity class extends ActionBarActivity class.

P.S.2 I set a breakpoint, but the debugger never stopped by this breakpoint.

Comment: Can you put some code?

Comment: @Mehul Shah, you can see part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use item.getItemId to get correct item. Try that.

Comment: You right, there are no getId() method for item, I use getItemId(), but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Try to put some legit code. its confusing. How do you know you are not getting onContextItemSelected? do you have any logmarkers or Toasts?